# How to Install And integrate Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Express .exe in window application

Tags: sql-server, windows, winforms, sql-server-2008

How to integrate Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Express .exe file in our window form application while we create an setup file for our application so that when client installs our .exe parallely Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Express should start installing with our application

Comment: [How to Embed SQL Server Express in an Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/user_ed/archive/2012/12/09/how-to-embed-sql-server-express-in-an-application.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you must install MS SQL Server additionally you can not integrate both of them. Once done, you can install your exe and starting using the application.